# Extending a Java class

Tags: java

There are two classes

```
public class Account
{
    public Acconut()
    {
       //constructor
    }
}


public class SavingsAccount extends Account
{
}
```

while doing the inheritance i have got an error message "cannont find symbol Symbol: constructor Account()" what might be the error in my code...??

Comment: I've fixed the formatting of your code. For future questions, please click the **[?]** link on the Ask a Question page for information about how to format code, etc.

Answer (score 6):

A typo in your code:

```
public Acconut()
```

Instead of

```
public Account()
```

Comment: So a *whole* Dan would have a rep of ~3360?

Comment: @Stephen: Don't you go starting the whole "milliskeets" thing again. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13827/can-we-measure-reputation-in-milliskeets